# Bash: Elegant way to set status?

Tags: bash, exit-status

- `true && echo foo` will print `foo`.
- `false && echo foo` will not print `foo`.
- `bash -c "exit $a" && echo foo` will print `foo` depending on `$a`.

Is there a more elegant way to write the last one? It seems a bit much having to start a shell simply to set the exit value. I am thinking something like:

- `return $a && echo foo`
- `exit $a && echo foo`

except `return` only works in functions and `exit` will cause `echo foo` never to be run.

Elegant in this context means:

- Easy to understand
- Portable
- Easy to read
- Easy to write
- Easy to remember
- Short
- High performance

E.g. if `true` took the exit code as an argument (and this was a documented feature), it would be very elegant.

So is there a more elegant way?

**Background**

One of the places this could be used is for:

```
$ parallel 'setexitval {= $_%=3 =} || echo $?' ::: 0 1 2 3
```

Kusalananda's version is probably the best. It is clear what is going on. It is not long and cumbersome to write. It is easy to remember and portable. The only drawback is that it forks another shell (it costs ~0.5 ms):

```
$ parallel '(exit {= $_%=3 =}) || echo $?' ::: 0 1 2 3
```

Another situation is when you want to simulate an error condition. Say, if you have a long running program, that sets different exit codes, and you are writing something that will react to the different exit codes. Instead of having to run the long running program, you can use `(exit $a)` to simulate the condition.

Comment: What’s wrong with true and false?

Comment: Your goal is to set $? to $a?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yep.

Comment: Why? Why not just check the value of `a`?

Comment: @mattdm Because I find that less elegant.

Comment: Can you define "elegant"?

Comment: @OleTange Can you explain 3 things: 1) why do you want to use `&&`  there ?  The whole purpose of `&&` is to run based on exit status,which is either success or failure.  There's really no need, because `exit 1` or `exit 2` or `exit 3` all look exactly the same as `false` to `&& echo foo` part. 2)  If your definition of `elegant` is `short`, well Kusalananda's answer is as short as it gets although it's seems kinda redundant. 3) If you're trying to set  `$?` ...why ? Can you explain the reasoning for need of such acrobatics ?

Comment: This question strongly smells like an "AB Problem" to me. There's a very good chance that *whatever you're actually trying to accomplish* that *led you to* wanting to manipulate the exit status could be more directly and more elegantly solved without having to manipulate the exit status this way.

Comment: How is the variable `a` being set?  I would bet that *that* is the inelegant part.  **If you are running `a=$?` at some point, then *don't do that.***  For example, `somecommand; a=$?; bash -c "exit $a" && echo foo` is a horribly, laughably complex way to write `somecommand && echo foo`.

Comment: I still do wonder what the actual use case would be. That example just seems to test if a number given as argument is divisible by 3, which doesn't seem very useful. For an actual command, checking the return value would be just `somecmd || echo "somecmd returned $?"`, or something like `parallel './somecmd {} || echo "{}: error $?" ' ::: foo bar doo`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a subshell that exits with the specified value.

This will output `5`:

```
a=5; ( exit $a ) && echo foo; echo $?
```

This will output `foo` and `0` (note, this zero is set by `echo` succeeding, not by the `exit` in the subshell):

```
a=0; ( exit $a ) && echo foo; echo $?
```

In your shortened form (without visibly setting `a` or investigating `$?` explicitly):

```
( exit $a ) && echo foo
```

---

My answer is one that comes from just taking the question at face value and solving it as a curious quiz, "how may we set `$?` (using handy notation)". I make no attempt to search for any deeper meaning or function or even context in this case (because non was given). I additionally do not judge the validity, efficiency or usability of the solution. I sometimes, in my answers, do say things like "... but don't do that, because...", followed up with "instead, do this...".  In this case, I'm choosing to interpret the question as simply a curious quiz.

---

Further background was now added to the question.

My take on the issue of forking a subshell is that scripts like GNU `configure` does this *all the time*, and that it's not terribly slow unless done in a really tight (long-running) loop.

I can't say much about the use of this in/with GNU `parallel` as I'm not a frequent user of that software.

Comment: Better and easier to understand than your last suggestion.

Comment: @OleTange Yes, I agree with that. The `(( !a ))` thing was a bit fragile. This (above) is actually _portable_ :-)

Comment: I'm *not* -1'ing because of this, but OP explicitly says "It seems a bit much having to start a shell simply to set the exit value." - and a subshell is doing exactly that: starting a separate shell process. (It's just a `fork` without an `exec` so it's more efficient than a full shell invocation because it can take advantage of CoW memory pages and other efficiencies in modern systems, but I feel like this answer should more explicitly draw attention to this fact.

Comment: @mtraceur I understand what you're saying, but I believe that the main point of the question was one of notation, and I interpreted the issue with "starting a shell" as "`bach -c "exit $a"` is too much to type".

Comment: Fair point. Thanks for providing the additional perspective into how you interpreted OP's statement on the matter.

Comment: Sidenote: one advantage to this naked exit-in-subshell method (without a function of any sort) besides conciseness over the function-return method: radical portability to *every* Bourne-like shell, as far as I know. (Not that it makes a difference in practice, because every Bourne-like shell in remotely practical use today has proper functions without any of the downsides (like wiping global `$@`) that would effect this.)

Comment: On further thought, I'm giving this a +1, despite my initial crticism. Because OP asked for "elegant", and this is certainly a good answer for many people's definitions of "elegant".

Answer (score 13):

Well, `return` works in a function, so let's make one:

```
$ ret() { return "${1-0}"; }
$ ret 1 || echo foo
foo
$ ret 123 ; echo $?
123
```

It needs a bit more setup than a subshell, but is shorter to use after that, and doesn't require forking a subshell.

Comment: I took a bit of inspiration out of your approach. Care to review my answer ?

Comment: IF that function had been part of Bash, I would find this more elegant than Kusalananda's answer. But having to define a function is around as cumbersome as using `bash -c "exit $a"`.

Comment: @OleTange, if you'd deigned to show the context where you needed this in the first place (or what the exact definition for elegance was), I wouldn't have suggested this. But you didn't, and I explicitly mentioned this needs more setup than running a subshell (namely, defining the function). I said "a bit" since only one line isn't much in a multiline script, but it obviously is too much for a one-liner. After that setup, it's much less cumbersome than `bash -c "exit $a"`.

Answer (score 5):

One option (probably faster but not really more elegant):

```
test "$a" -eq 0 && echo foo
```

It executes `echo` but does not set the exit value to `$a`, so it is a mediocre solution.

Answer (score 4):

Let's examine your assumptions:

- `true && echo foo` will print foo. Correct because `&&` adheres to AND with short circuit logic; because of left-associativity in `&&` and `||` operators if left-most command returned success exit status 0 (which `true` does always) , the right-most command to this operator will run.
- `false && echo foo` will not print foo. Exactly the opposite case of explained above.
- `bash -c "exit $a" && echo foo` will print foo depending on `$a`. Essentially wrong assumption that `$a` controls `&&`. Because  `&&`  is AND logic, it recognizes only two states - success or failure, where failure is any exit status above 0. Thus `exit 1` and `exit 2` and `exit 3` - all are irrelevant to `&&`;  failure is failure regardless of `$a` value; that is why `echo foo` doesn't run.

Therefore the answer is *no, there is no more elegant way* to do something that operates under wrong assumption anyway.  However, if  your purpose is to set exit status via command, that's sufficient to use what Kusalananda's answer suggests - a subshell.  I personally don't see that any different from `bash -c` part, except that subshell may be implemented as child process/forked process instead of separate process; still not ideal. Note that `$?` also shouldn't be set by user via variable - it is intended for commands to communicate success or failure.

Let's switch focus on `$a` for a second. Why set `$?` and `echo foo`, if you can directly check `$a` ?  It makes no sense to place `$a` value where it doesn't belong anyway, i.e. in `$?`. I would recommend shifting focus from "elegant"( whatever that means ) to "logical" and "working".

---

Alright, but let's play your game. Taking a modest inspiration from [ilkkachu's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423706/85039). This approach, however, removes need to force echo conditional execution. It will go to echo if an only if it provided variable indicates success, and `return` prevents its execution.

```
$ thing(){ [ "${1-0}" -eq 0 ] || return "$1" ; echo "foo"; }
$ thing
foo
$ thing 0
foo
$ thing 1
$ echo $?
1
$ thing 2
$ echo $?
2
```

What may not be obvious is that you can do `thing $a`

Comment: +1: good tackling the probable conception underlying the question (especially given the limited insights the question actually gives into it). As an aside, I would suggest highlighting ilkkachu's answer at least as prominently as Kusalanda's, because the function route is more efficient and with the right function naming will be more readable than the naked subshell route (and while a function wrapper for the subshell method would gain the same readability advantage, it would lose the only advantages of conciseness and radical-portability-to-ancient-Bourne-shells).

Comment: @mtraceur Agreed, since ilkkachu's answer doesn't produce a separate process.  Conceptually, though...even function seems as reinventing wheel where one even doesn't need a wheel

Comment: @Kusalananda And it's a decent answer, as always when it comes to your answers. Just the "quiz" itself  seems to make wrong assumptions, which OP despite repeated comments did not clarify. We can set `$?`, it is indeed curious how to do it, but it doesn't mean it's intended to be set by the user.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy And the decision I make there is to not care, at least not until I see it in some form of context.

Comment: @Kusalananda I think in this decision you're probably wiser than most people here :)

Comment: I updated my answer , please review the solution

Comment: I find this cumbersome to write and remember, and much harder to understand than Kusalananda's solution.